# Duplicate emails sent through AWS SES

Tags: php, amazon-ses

I am working with Amazon AWS and trying to send emails using their SES service.

I am using their recommended library (http://www.orderingdisorder.com/aws/ses/) to send the emails out.

The issue I am having is that it is sending out duplicate emails. I have, using echoing data out to screen,  seen that no where is the code doubling up, the call to send the email is only being called once, yet consistently 2 emails are being received.

I echoed out the data being sent through CURL and there was only one email address listed, yet two emails are received.

Am I doing something wrong or is there an issue with SES?

Comment: Have you tried other email addresses? Very unlikely to be a culprit but once I had an email address that would fwd emails to an alias of the same email address.

Comment: Also, while you're having this issue, in the content of the email append the output from this function `debug_backtrace()`. For instance if your email content is in a variable called $content, do this: `$content .= print_r(debug_backtrace(), true);`. This should give you the stack trace to ensure that it's getting called once.

Comment: I'm not sure where you see *that* library as the recommended one.  The  official PHP SDK is the recommended SES library.

Comment: @Charles I assumed it was as the only thing that appears in "sample code" refers to it not the PHP SDK.